# GCC dll for use with Delphi ShareMem application

Tags: c, delphi, gcc

So I have a host Delphi 7 application, which has to allocate and destroy strings in it's dll. Surely, dll is also written in object Pascal and uses `ShareMem` first of all and carries `Borlndmm.dll` in it's folder all the time.

Right now I need to rewrite this dll in C (mingw is preferable) and compile dll for main application, written in Delphi 7.

How can that be achieved? Do I need to rewrite borland memory manager in C or should I write some interface to use it with `borlndmm.dll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Sharemem` when you are allocating using the Delphi heap in one module, and deallocating them using the same heap in a different module. The `Sharemem` unit ensures that memory allocations in both modules share the same allocator.

Now, you can do that with a Delphi executable and a Delphi DLL, provided that both executable and DLL are compiled with the same version of Delphi. But you cannot do that at all with a Delphi executable and a C DLL. You cannot allocate memory in Delphi and expect your C DLL to be able to deallocate it. C runtimes will not map malloc/free to a call to shared memory manager.

Your question makes it clear that you would like to allocate a Delphi string in Delphi and pass it to a C DLL. And then free it in that C DLL. Well you cannot reasonably expect to do that. A Delphi string has to be managed by the Delphi runtime. You don't have that available in your C DLL.

Now, it's certainly possible that you could devise a way to emulate the Delphi runtime in C sufficient so that you could interop with strings. But I think that's a bad idea. Instead, what you should do is follow standard interop practice:

1. Arrange that memory is deallocated in the same module that allocates it.
2. Only pass standard interop types between the two modules. That is: integral types, floating point types, null-terminated string pointers. And compound types, records and arrays, that only contain standard interop types.

---

**Update**

You state in comments:

> The problem is I don't have soucecode of Delphi app.

That leaves you in something of a bind. You cannot change the interface to the DLL. The solution is to make a thin wrapper DLL written in Delphi 7. That wrapper DLL should use `Sharemem` and can create strings that are destroyed by the host executable. The wrapper DLL forwards to your new C DLL any requests from the host executable. The interop between the Delphi 7 wrapper and the new C DLL follows the standard interop guidelines.

The wrapper DLL is what is known as an *adapter*.

Comment: Thank you, but purpose of dll is to create and pass string to main application and then dispose it. I actually need recompiled version of host app in delphi as it's too complicated to compile dll under gcc.

Comment: Pass a null terminated character array between modules. Compiling DLL under mingw is simple.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Is there some guide how to share types between `C++` and `Delphi`? Such as Strings, Arrays, Records, Classes etc.
`FPC` has a feature where it can use classes compiled by `GCC`.

Comment: @user It's probably a bad idea to do so and probably not even tractable.